# Mockito performance using spy vs no spy

Tags: android, unit-testing, jvm, mockito

Lets say I have a "Presenter":

```
class Presenter
```

and I will write multiple tests for that class.

There are two ways to create the presenter:

1.

```
class PresenterTests {

    @Test
    fun test_attach() { 
       val presenter = Presenter()

       // presenter.doThings()
       // verify / asserts
    }
}
```

2.

```
class PresenterTests {

    @Test
    fun test_attach() { 
       val presenter = spy(Presenter())

       // presenter.doThings()
       // verify / asserts
    }
}
```

Is there any performance issue if I use always spy for all of my objects and just check them whenever it's really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any significant performance penalty when using `spy()`, but you might introduce unexpected or unwanted behavior for other reasons if you spy on everything.

From [Javadoc for spy()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-):

> Mockito *does not* delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is that when an *unstubbed* method is called *on the spy* but *not on the real instance*, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

This could result in unexpected behavior in your tests – depending on how they're written – if you use `spy()` everywhere.

> Watch out for final methods. Mockito doesn't mock final methods so the bottom line is: when you spy on real objects + you try to stub a final method = trouble. Also you won't be able to verify those method as well.

This is a limitation within Mockito that might result in problems.

Also, there's this statement (from same Javadoc) which is counter to the idea of spying on everything:

> Real spies should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when dealing with legacy code.